# Exposed query select null value

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I'm facing an issue with a query using Exposed (Kotlin).

I've a table where a field is a datetime which is nullable

```
object MyTable: IntIdTable("myTable") {
   val myDate = datetime("myDate").nullable()
}
```

I want to create a query which returns objects matching rules.

My rules are :

- Select objects where "myDate" > current date
- Select objects where "myDate" < current date
- Select objects where "myDate" is null

Until now, I achieve to retrieve value for both "<" and ">" :

```
val query = MyTable.select {
   when {
       includeCurrent && includeEnded -> Op.TRUE
       includeCurrent -> MyTable.myDate.greater(DateTime.now())
       includeEnded -> MyTable.myDate.less(DateTime.now())
       else -> Op.FALSE
   }
}
```

But, when "includeCurrent" is true, I want to return objects where myDate is null

Is this possible?

I've try:

```
MyTable.myDate.eq<DateTime?>(null)
```

But I can't use it because it's an Op

How could I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: There are `isNull/isNotNull` functions and also you can use `Op.nullOp`

Answer (score 0):

You can use isNull extencion. It`s work for me [image: example in my code] [image]